# Docker. Exec npm command in different folder

Tags: docker, npm

I want to run `npm install` command in container.
But simple: `docker exec container npm install` is not the right thing for me.

I want to run this command in `/home/client` but my working directory in container is `/home`

Is that possible?
I don't want to enter container and I don't want to change working environment.

**Edit 1**
Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY . /home
WORKDIR /home
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python-pip \
    postgresql \
    rabbitmq-server \
    libpq-dev \
    python-dev \
    npm \
    mongodb
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run \
-tid \
-p 8000:8000 \
-v $(PWD):/home \
--name container \
-e DB_NAME \
-e DB_USER \
-e DB_USER_PASSWORD \
-e DB_HOST \
-e DB_PORT \
container
```

Two commands in order to prove there is a directory `/home/client`:

```
docker exec container pwd
```

Gives: `/home`

```
docker exec container ls client
```

Gives:

```
node_modules
package.json
src
webpack.config.js
```

That's node modules from my host.

**Edit 2**
When run:

```
docker exec container cd /home/client
```

It produces the following error:

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: It is not necessary to have `COPY . /home` in your Dockerfile and `-v $(PWD):/home` in your run command. Used at the same time, this might produce confusing behavior. Because those do *almost* the same thing (but not).

Comment: What output does this command produce? `docker exec container cd /home/client`

Comment: Made edit 2 to question. I need to `COPY . /home` in order to `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` from the Dockerfile.

Comment: The best way to do that would be `COPY requirements.txt /home/requirements.txt`. I don't know what's going on with `docker exec ... cd ...`. I'm quite sure that command's available in the container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is possible with:

```
docker exec {container} sh -c "cd /home/client && npm install"
```

Thanks to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it's possible. You can do it one of two ways.

#### Method 1

Do it in a single command like this:

```
$ docker exec container sh -c "cd /home/client && npm install"
```

Or like this (as an arg to `npm install`):

```
$ docker exec container npm install --prefix /home/client
```

#### Method 2

Use an interactive terminal:

```
$ docker exec -it container /bin/bash
# cd /home/client
# npm install
```

Comment: None of options worked. `$ docker exec container "cd /home/client && npm install"` lead to `rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd /home/client/ && npm install\": stat cd /home/client/ && npm install: no such file or directory"`. And `docker exec container npm install /home/client` lead to: `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/package.json'` But package.json exists in /home/client

Comment: Both errors are happening because `/home/client` does not exist in your container. How did you verify that the directory actually exists? It needs to exist _in the container_, not on your host machine. I'm guessing it only exists on your host machine. In which case, you can fix it simply by mounting that directory into the container as a volume at the same location: `-v /home/client:/home/client`

Comment: post a reproducer, or at least your Dockerfile and `docker run` command used

Comment: Made an edit to a question. Haven't understood what you mean "post a reproducer"

Comment: Method 1a: Docker is trying to exec an executable named `"cd /home/client && npm install"` which doesn't exist.  Use `docker exec {container} sh -c "cd /home/client && npm install"`

Comment: Method 1b: `npm install <folder>` doesn't run an `npm install` on the target folder. It installs the package from the target folder into a `node_modules` directory either in the current directory, or a parents if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I should have tried the command myself but I wasn't on a machine with Docker installed at the time.